# How do I resolve /c/Program Files/nodejs/node: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' error?

Tags: nvm, nvm-windows

I've installed nvm, downloaded a version of node and then `use` it.

When I try to install a package, or run `node --version` or `npm --version`, I get the following error:

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe: line 1: `<html>'
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe: line 1: `<html>'
```

It seems as if the nodejs folder inside of Program Files isn't mapping over to where nvm is installed. I am unsure on how to fix this.